# Are there any details about the contract that Aaron Taylor-Johnson signed to be a part of the Marvel Cinematic Universe?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron

Aaron Taylor-Johnson was cast as Pietro Maximoff, AKA Quicksilver in the sequel to *The Avengers/Avengers Assemble*, *Avengers: Age of Ultron*.

Most actors/actresses sign multi-picture contracts when working with Marvel Studios so that they can be called upon again to star in future films if need be.

Does anyone know how many films Aaron Taylor-Johnson signed on to do?

Warning: There may be spoilers regarding *Avengers: Age of Ultron* in the comments and answers posted.

Comment: Well think about it, in the comics they bring any person back with Inhumane blood (i.e a mutant like him) and if they are following the comics which they are trying to a degree they will, also why else would they bring his dead body with him if they had no intention of attempted revival, also scarlet witch also has marriage and a baby with vision.... So anything is possible hsha

Comment: T.A.H.I.T.I. was sepicifically designed for a fallen Avenger

Comment: If you look at [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3498820/), most of the Avengers, notably Scarlet Witch, are listed to be appearing in *Captain America: Civil War*. He is not.

Comment: Of course they are probably bringing quicksilver back because marvel always has some way of bringing big characters back such as nick fury,phil coulson, and loki to name a few. With such a lovable character killing him off would only mean quicksilver lovers would be too devastated to continue watching the movies .

Answer (score 8):

It seems his contract was indeed for a single movie based on the following excerpt:

> Quiksilver is DEAD. 100%, he's not coming back any time soon, there are no plans. 
> No LMD, no escaping bullets, no retcon. 
> Kevin Feige said he is dead and wanted to make sure people understood that.

[Source.](http://www.reddit.com/r/marvelstudios/comments/350fsy/kevin_feige_on_avengers_age_of_ultron_will/)

Answer (score 3):

He *probably* only signed on for one: Age of Ultron.

(For obvious reasons)

From [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2395427/trivia?item=tr2182877):

> It took Joss Whedon a year to convince Aaron Taylor-Johnson to accept the role of Quicksilver. Johnson was concerned over the intensity of the Marvel contracts, the time constraints, and the fact that it was going to be such a large cast. Even after he accepted the role, he was still nervous, but was comforted after he learned that his friend and Godzilla (2014) co star Elizabeth Olsen would be playing his sister and would be his filming partner through most of the movie.

This is the only information I can find on it...

Comment: I've seen the film twice now, but the events that transpire hardly write him out of any future films; see Bucky Barnes, Steve Rogers, Nick Fury, Loki, Agent Coulson etc. If you have any proof of a 1 film contract, please add it to your answer.

Comment: You're right - there is a possibility for him to appear in films that transpired before the events of Age of Ultron

Comment: @davidlimux And afterwards - it would hardly be a surprise if they somehow bought him back, especially considering the nature of his sisters powers in the comic books.

Comment: Thanks for adding that information. The problem is that I can't tell if it took a year for Whedon and Taylor-Johnson to convince Marvel Studios to sign a one picture deal, or if it took a year for Whedon and Marvel Studios to convince Taylor-Johnson to sign a multi-picture deal. It can be read either way, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere that BOTH Aaron Taylor-Johnson and Elizabeth Olsen were signed on for multi-picture deals as Quicksilver and Scarlett Witch respectively so, if I had to guess they will most likely bring him back IF this were true and they probably could do it considering they established Vision's mind gem and Scarlett Witch's powers. But, this is all speculation from what I was told and where I read.

Comment: I'd love to see where you read this if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this website, it shows how many contracts each marvel actor has. It says Johnson and Olsen have signed for multi-picture contracts. So who knows, quicksilver may return because of this and because of the time gem or scarlet wiches powers to bring back characters which she did in the comics.

https://captainzach616.wordpress.com/2014/09/25/contract-lengths-for-marvel-actors/

Comment: Thanks for the useful link, but just FYI: the page explicitly says that previous announcements about multi-movie contracts did not necessarily hold water, and it's looking like Aaron Taylor-Johnson may have indeed only been brought on for the one Avengers movie.